# Update multiple locations of one-dimensional array with minimum/one line(s) of code

Tags: c++, c, logic, pseudocode

I have one-dimentional array initialized globally in C++

```
Gfloat cone1[] = { 0.0f, 2.4f, -11.0f, 30.0f, -1.5, 0.0, 0.0 };
```

I want to update its all values with different numbers of my choice within my main function writing minimum/one line(s) of code.

Is it possible?

I don't want to do like :-

```
cone1[0] = 12f , cone1[1] = 56f; ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to switch to using `std::vector` or `std::array` you can use uniform initialization and an assignment.

The following example uses `std::vector` for a variable sized array.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<Gfloat> cone1 { 0.0f, 2.4f, -11.0f };

    cone1 = { 30.0f, -1.5, 0.0 };
}
```

The following example uses `std::array` for a fixed sized array.

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<Gfloat, 3> cone1 { 0.0f, 2.4f, -11.0f };

    cone1 = { 30.0f, -1.5, 0.0 };
}
```

Comment: Tried replacing my code with your suggested code but [this](http://sphotos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/999017_3104347665314_295266663_n.jpg) error occurred. I am using Eclipse with MinGW.

Comment: The error it pretty clear. Uniform initialization and `initializer_list` are C++11 features. Add `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` to the command line options to enable C++11 mode. I also suggest updating to a newer version of GCC.

Comment: I have updated GCC to newer one but error is same. Please tell me how to give that command line argument. I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Comment: You still need to add `-std-c++11` or `-std-c++0x` to the command line. The error message is pretty clear about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the values you want to replace with in another array, you could use std::copy:

```
std::copy(newCone, newCone + 7, cone1);
```

Comment: I want to update the same array inside main function with my chosen numbers writing minimum code instead of updating cell by cell.

Comment: Well, my answer is one-line, and if you don't put your chosen numbers in some other array, then I don't see a way of doing that other than "cone[1] = 12f etc".
Just define "Gfloat newCone[] = { 12f, 56f, ...}".

Comment: Thanks for this. Let see if any one else has the solution or not! Thanks again though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it on one line, then do it on one line:

```
cone1[0] = 12f; cone1[1] = 56f; ... // and so on
```

Making it all appear on one line / aiming for minium code though doesn't make it any more efficient though - readable code across more lines is better than tightly packed code that takes up less space in a file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem as @Captain Obvlious suggested.

Replace **-c -fmessage-length=0** with **-c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11**

Make sure you leave a **space** between *-c -fmessage-length=0* and *-std=c++11*

Otherwise your project will show that it is build but won't create .exe file.